# WinForms: Возможность поиска лишь по некоторым параметрам в DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

В `DataGridView` есть таблица, взятая в БД из `MySQL`. Пользователь может делать поиск значений из колонок `"Тип транспорта"` и `"Тип питания"`, вписав необходимые значения в `TransComboBox` и `EatComboBox` соответственно. Я хочу, чтобы была возможность сделать поиск даже с пустым параметром. К примеру, если в `EatComboBox` ничего не записывать, а только в `TransComboBox`, то не выводит ничего, а нужно, чтобы выводились элементы, удовлетворяющие запросу в `TransComboBox`. Надо ли в таком случае делать какую-то проверку на пустое значение в `EatComboBox`, и как тогда будет выглядеть решение? Заранее спасибо. Вот код:

```
dvSearch.RowFilter = "[Тип транспорта] LIKE '" + TransComboBox.Text + 
"' AND [Тип питания] LIKE '" + EatComboBox.Text + "'";
```

Comment: `if (пустой TransComboBox) RowFilter = "Тип питания] ..."` и т. п.

Comment: Если в обоих комбо выбраны значения, то формируете фильтр с помощью AND. Если в одном не выбрано - то в фильтре лишь одно значение. Если оба комбо не выбраны, то фильтр вообще не задавать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а если, к примеру, 6 параметров у меня, тогда так тоже получится?

Comment: Тогда получаем комбинаторный взрыв. Множество `if` и заранее написанных вариантов фильтров. Это большая проблема. Решается она по разному. Например, в SQL придумали динамические запросы. А в C# для этого придумали LINQ - он легко композируется. Но тогда нужно отказаться от `RowFilter`.

Comment: Хорошо, полистаю эти темы, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема поиска по нескольким комбинациям параметров довольно остра. Я думаю, стоит расписать способы её решения.

Чтобы код был коротким, я буду именовать колонки одной буквой: `A`, `B`, `C`.
Также одной буквой - `a`, `b`, `c` - будут заданы значения для поиска.

То есть `a = TransComboBox.Text` и т. п. А если значение в комбобоксе не выбрано, то `a = null`.

Также для удобства используем интерполяцию строк.

---

Во-первых, можно просто вручную перечислить все возможные комбинации.

```
string filter = null;

if (a != null && b != null)
    filter = $"[A] LIKE '{a}' AND [B] LIKE '{b}'";
else if (a != null && b == null)
    filter = $"[A] LIKE '{a}'";
else if (a == null && b != null)
    filter = $"[B] LIKE '{b}'";

dvSearch.RowFilter = filter;
```

Надеюсь, вы пишете не под древний .NET Framework. В последних версиях C# появился паттерн-матчинг, с помощью которого такой код записывается лаконично и понятно:

```
string? filter = (a, b) switch
{
    (not null, not null) => $"[A] LIKE '{a}' AND [B] LIKE '{b}'",
    (not null, null)     => $"[A] LIKE '{a}'",
    (null, not null)     => $"[B] LIKE '{b}'",
    (null, null)         => null
};
```

При двух параметрах получаем четыре комбинации (4-я - `filter = null`). При трёх - восемь. Если у вас 6 параметров, то возможных комбинаций будет 64. Вручную всё это описывать, а главное потом поддерживать - мрак... И даже switch expression не спасёт.

---

Следующий способ - использование условий в самом языке запросов.

```
string filter = $"([A] LIKE '{a}' OR '{a}' = '') AND ([B] LIKE '{b}' OR '{b}' = '')";
```

Выглядит довольно сложно. Перепишу в несколько строк:

```
string filter = @$"
    ([A] LIKE '{a}' OR '{a}' = '')
AND ([B] LIKE '{b}' OR '{b}' = '')
AND ([C] LIKE '{c}' OR '{c}' = '')
";
```

В таком виде даже множество комбинаций параметров записываются достаточно кратко.
Такой способ иногда используют в SQL-запросах в РСУБД. За подробностями отсылаю к статье [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). У него может быть плохая производительность на больших объёмах. Но у вас в `DataTable` на клиенте данных в любом случае мало, так что можно смело использовать.

---

Другой способ - составление запроса на лету. Наверное, самый *любимый* способ большинства начинающих (да и любых) разработчиков.

```
string filter = null;

if (a != null)
    filter = $"[A] LIKE '{a}' AND ";

if (b != null)
    filter += $"[B] LIKE '{b}' AND ";

if (c != null)
    filter += $"[C] LIKE '{c}' AND ";

if (filter != null)
    filter = filter[..^5]; // удаляем последний ' AND '
```

В данном конкретном случае этот способ оказывается несложным и лёгким для понимания. Однако, когда нужны не только простые сравнения, но и попадание в диапазон значений (`>` и `<`) и объединений разных условий `and` и `or`, тогда
составление запроса путём конкатенации строк может стать очень сложной задачей с удалением ставших ненужными частей.
В нашем случае нужно лишь удалить в конце лишний `AND`, что просто.

Покажу ещё один способ конструирования фильтра. Просто, чтобы был:

```
List<string> parts = new();

if (a != null)
    parts.Add($"[A] LIKE '{a}'");

if (b != null)
    parts.Add($"[B] LIKE '{b}'");

if (c != null)
    parts.Add($"[C] LIKE '{c}'");

string filter = string.Join(" AND ", parts);
```

---

Ещё один способ - использование LINQ.
Большое достоинство LINQ - композируемость запросов. Это огромное преимущество при работе с настоящими базами данных. Можно динамически добавлять любые условия, фильтрацию, сортировку, отображение, мапинг. Итоговый запрос будет сконструирован автоматически.

```
var query = dataTable.AsEnumerable();

if (a != null)
    query = query.Where(row => row.Field<string>("A") == a);

if (b != null)
    query = query.Where(row => row.Field<string>("B") == b);

if (c != null)
    query = query.Where(row => row.Field<string>("C") == c);
                        
var result = query.CopyToDataTable();            
dataGridView.DataSource = result;
```

Но тут мы получаем ещё один `DataTable`, а вы используете `DataView`. Могут быть нюансы в поведении.
А главное, тут используется прямое сравнение `==` двух значений. Между тем у вас используется `LIKE`.

Для имитации `LIKE` придётся подключить регулярки.

```
string patternA = $".*{a}.*";
string patternB = $".*{b}.*";
string patternC = $".*{c}.*";
```

Создаём шаблоны для каждого значения. Здесь wildcards и в начале, и в конце. Поправьте шаблоны, как нужно вам.

После чего используем их в запросах:

```
query = query.Where(row => Regex.IsMatch(row.Field<string>("A"), patternA));
```