# Как создать SQL запрос с динамическим условием WHERE (C# WPF Npsql)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, npgsql

Имеется окно (WPF) для поиска данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4 поля на картинке принадлежат таблице companies (словарь с названиями компаний и другими полями). Результат поиска должен содержать строки из главной таблицы products, которые содержат соответствующий id компании. Ближе к сути. Предположим, что у меня есть только  Id TextBox. Тогда мой запрос выглядел бы так:

```
SELECT * FROM products JOIN companies ON products.company_id = company.id WHERE company.id = ...;
```

Однако, у меня есть 4 TextBox'а и мне нужно условие "where", которое будет динамически обновляться в зависимости от наполнения этих самых TextBox'ов. Например, заполнены 2 из 4-х TextBox'ов:

```
SELECT * FROM products JOIN companies ON products.company_id = companies.id WHERE <<Название_поля1>> = <<Текст_ТекстБокса1>> AND <<Название_поля2>> = <<Текст_ТекстБокса2>>;
```

Как такое реализовать, используя Npgsql?

Comment: Знаете о существовании Entity Framework? Или Linq2Sql?

Comment: не рекомендую ни EF, ни Linq. Проблемы не решит, только новые добавит. Драйвер, который хотели добавили в проект? хоть какой-то запрос из программы можете выполнить? далее делайте if-ми динамический запрос. столкнетесь с дальнейшими проблемами, пишите.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, то есть, в ADO.NET без банальных if-ов не обойтись?

Comment: можно, как aepot советует, через ORM делать. я, к сожалению (или к счастью), не владею ни тем, ни тем.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417941/184217 - здесь я описал 4 способа применительно к `DataTable`. Применительно к БД и sql будет то же самое, лишь небольшие изменения в синтаксисе.

Comment: Удалось разобраться? / Нужно ли переписать тот ответ конкретно для SQL и БД?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, использовал циклы